# Escaping Bootstrap Columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have two Bootstrap columns in my row, one is wide and tall and the others are short and narrow

[image: Two column display]

However, on mobile devices (which I am targeting as anything below `lg`) I want to change the order of these columns, effectively splitting into three

1. Photo Consent
2. Organisation Details
3. Images

However, as the Photo Consent and Images are in the same column, I can't get this layout right - I either end up with both Photo Consent *and* Images above the Organisation, or I can get the right mobile layout but then Images ends up on a new row below on desktop.

Is there a way to achieve the desired layout in Bootstrap?

Here's the relevant markup for these columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- first column - Organisation Details -->
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
      <div class="card card-body mb-3">
         <h3 class="text-center">Organisation Details</h3>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
               <div class="form-group mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="255" required />
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
               <div class="form-group mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label" for="slug">URL Slug</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="URL Slug" maxlength="300" />
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
               <colour-picker title="Primary Colour" name="primary" value="#000000">
               </colour-picker>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
               <colour-picker title="Secondary Colour" name="secondary" value="#FFFFFF"></colour-picker>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea rows="7" id="description" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description" ></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <!-- second column - photo consent and images -->
   <!-- on mobile, would prefer to split this column in two and have Photo Consent show above Org Details -->
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
      <div class="card card-body mb-3">
         <h3 class="text-center"><a href="consent">Photo Consent</a></h3>
         <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="consent">Can we take photos and videos of this organisation?</label>
            <select class="form-control style-by-value" name="consent" id="consent" required>
               <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
               <option value="1">No</option>
               <option value="2">Yes, but...</option>
               <option value="3">Yes</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <small>Consent type updated from web order</small>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-body mb-3">
         <h3 class="text-center">Images</h3>
         <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">File uploads are currently unavailable</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The only other thing I could think was to duplicate the columns and use a combination of `d-none` / `d-none-lg` to show/hide the relevant layout depending on the screen - but this is all wrapped in a `form` and I have concerns it could get a bit messy (besides the messiness of duplicated columns!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Luke Reafactored your code.
added comments near each section please go through.

1. adding `clearfix d-flex flex-wrap` on the row
   we are making the child elements inside the row to float, so adding `clearfix` will solve the issue of float elements.
   `d-flex flex-wrap` setting the display to flex, and `flex-wrap` makes child elements wrap to next line when there is no enough space.
2. adding `float-start order-2` on `organisation block`
   `float-start` makes the block to `float:left`, `order-2` - because we made the parent row to display as flex using `d-flex` , order class controls the position of the block when it is displayed as flex
3. rest of the blocks are floated to right using `float-end`, and following the same order concept, we are ordering the blocks.

i suggest you refer `order` concept in `flex-box` which helps to solve these issues.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-SbiR/eusphKoMVVXysTKG/7VseWii+Y3FdHrt0EpKgpToZeemhqHeZeLWLhJutz/2ut2Vw1uQEj2MbRF+TVBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- added clearfix and display classes -->
  <div class="row clearfix d-flex flex-wrap d-lg-block">
    <!-- first column - Organisation Details -->
    <!-- added order classes and float classes -->
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 float-start order-2">
      <div class="card card-body mb-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Organisation Details</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="255" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label class="form-label" for="slug">URL Slug</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="URL Slug" maxlength="300" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <colour-picker title="Primary Colour" name="primary" value="#000000">
            </colour-picker>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <colour-picker title="Secondary Colour" name="secondary" value="#FFFFFF"></colour-picker>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
          <label class="form-label" for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea rows="7" id="description" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- second column - photo consent -->
    <!-- added order classes and float classes -->
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 float-end order-1">
      <div class="card card-body mb-3">
        <h3 class="text-center"><a href="consent">Photo Consent</a></h3>
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
          <label for="consent">Can we take photos and videos of this organisation?</label
              >
              <select
                class="form-control style-by-value"
                name="consent"
                id="consent"
                required
              >
                <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
                <option value="1">No</option>
                <option value="2">Yes, but...</option>
                <option value="3">Yes</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <small>Consent type updated from web order</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- moved images out of the above div and made it seperate -->
        <!-- images -->
        <!-- added order classes and float classes -->
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 float-end order-3">
          <div class="card card-body mb-3">
            <h3 class="text-center">Images</h3>
            <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
              File uploads are currently unavailable
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, that's perfect, thank you so much!! Would you mind explaining a bit about what the new classes do please?